# How to Have Different Colors per Category in a Bar Chart in SSRS 2008 R2

Tags: reporting-services

In my Bar Chart I just have 1 series (let's say, sales) and 10 categories (let's say, regions).
I want the bar for each category to display in a different color, automatically.
I could add a `SWITCH` operation for the "Fill" property, but it's not practical since the category values are data driven and change constantly.

Comment: I am not sure how relevant this is, but since SSRS charting is based on original Dundas chart (and similar to ASP.NET charting) if you have access to underlying chart object model, you can assign colors to individual data points, e.g. looping thru collection of series do something like `oChart.Series[i].Points[0].Color = aSomeColorArray[i]`

Comment: What about instead of using SWITCH for the fill - point it to a Dataset field? After that all you have to do is supply the color in that field from the datasource.

Comment: That's really what I did: I have a calculated field `color` and give it a value depending on the `SWITCH`, but that only gives me the data I expect. Thanks a lot anyhow!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For consistency, you might want to assign a color to each region so they always display with the same color. You could add a RegionColor field to your table and then assign this to the `Fill` property of your Series Properties:

```
=Fields!RegionColor.Value
```

Then whenever your report users see blue, they know it is a certain region, yellow is another region, consistently across all your reports.

This works best for a limited number of regions.

Comment: Thanks Chris. I did that as a calculated field instead of in the DB. In many cases it would be better in the DB as you said, but in my particular case I think it's better like this because the source is an XML file that I don't have access to its generation.

Comment: In that case, instead using a calculated field, you could have an XML file of region colors, use that as a dataset, then use a lookup from the region to the color, e.g. =Lookup(Fields!Region.Value, Fields!Region.Value, Fields!Color.Value, "RegionColorsDataset") this effectively replaces your calculation with a bit more flexibility and you still have the consistency of colors across reports.